# ModelChoiceField Concatenate two fields in one field - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Hi i dont know the way to transform two fields model into one 'custom' to propose a unique field (pass ('fieldA','fieldB') to ('fieldA fieldB').

I am trying to build an inner model function but without excepted result...

## models.py

```
class Referencebank(models.Model):
    idtable1 = models.AutoField(db_column='idtable1', primary_key=True)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    subspecies = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)


    def getScientifName(self):
        return str(self.genus) + " " + str(self.species);


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'table1'
```

## forms.py

```
class ScientifNameForm(forms.Form):

    for ref in Referencebank.objects.all():

        queryset = ref.getScientifName();
        print("\n queryset")


    scientifName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Referencebank.objects.values_list('genus','species').order_by('genus').distinct(),
                                                   empty_label="(Nothing)",
                                                   required=False,
                                                   help_text="Select the bacteria",label='Scientific Name')
```

In forms.py, the `for` loop execute correctly the result that i want display in modelchoicefield

I want something like that

```
        scientifName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Referencebank.objects.values_list('scientificName').order_by('scientificN').distinct(),
                                                   empty_label="(Nothing)",
                                                   required=False,
                                                   help_text="Select the bacteria",label='Scientific Name')
```

Comment: Would it be easier to define `__str__` on the model itself and use a `queryset=Referencebank.objects.all()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to override the `label_to_instance` method of [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

```
from django import forms

class ScientificNameChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.getScientifName()
```

Then use your custom field in your form.

```
class ScientifNameForm(forms.Form):
    scientifName = ScientificNameChoiceField(
        queryset=Referencebank.objects.all(),
        help_text="Select the bacteria",
        label='Scientific Name',
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you meant `ScientificNameChoiceField` instead of `ReferencebankChoiceField` in `class ScientifNameForm(forms.Form)`.  I have this error with your answer `AttributeError: 'ScientificNameChoiceField' object has no attribute 'getScientifName'` maybe i dont really understand some tips about models/forms in django.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of issues. The name is up to you but it should be consistent. In the `label_from_instance`, it should be `obj.getScientifName()` instead of `self.getScientifName()`.

Comment: Perfect answer =)